# How can I get a particular objectForKey with the same key in a dictionary?

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsdictionary

I get a JSON from a url, but it have the same "key" repeatedly.

Here is the JSON -> [link](http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?latlng=37.785834,-122.406417&sensor=true)

I pass all data to a NSDictionary and select the specific node that I want that is "long_name" with this:

```
[[[allDataDictionary objectForKey:@"results"]valueForKey:@"address_components"]valueForKey:@"long_name"]
```

The result:

> (
>       1,
>       "Stockton Street",
>       Downtown,
>       "S\U00e3o Francisco",
>       "San Francisco",
>       "San Francisco",
>       "Calif\U00f3rnia",
>       "Estados Unidos",
>       94108
>   )

I want the fifth element. How can I do this?

Comment: 1) That's not a dictionary. b) Dictionaries don't have multiples of the same key.

Comment: the "result" key contain an array, and each element of the array is a dictionary. so get the array, and for each index you have a dictionary with those keys

Comment: You're wrong Josh... I'm getting a JSON code and putting into a Dictionary.

Comment: No, I'm not. The thing that you put after "The result:" is _not_ a dictionary. It's an array.

Comment: No, It's a dictionary...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution, I have to use NSMutableDictionary:

It's a little complicated, but works

```
[[[[[allDataDictionary objectForKey:@"results"]valueForKey:@"address_components"]valueForKey:@"long_name"]objectAtIndex:0]objectAtIndex:5]
```

The answer is: San Francisco

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

This is a JSON array, so you can access to each element with objectAtIndex:

```
id obj1= [json objectAtIndex: i];
```

If you use a newer compiler it's the equivalent of this:

```
id obj1= json[i];
```